# Need help fixing an error. Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

Tags: java

I have a program that I have be working on that converts binary to decimal.  The code works for small binary numbers entered by the user but when I enter a long binary number a error happens and I get this.

Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: "01100101110011011010111000000101"
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLong(Scanner.java:2271)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLong(Scanner.java:2225)
    at Binary.binToDec(Binary.java:30)
    at Driver.main(Driver.java:27)

Here is my code that has the problem.

```
 public void binToDec() {

    long binary;

    Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
    binary = num.nextLong();
    System.out.println("You entered the binary number " + binary);
    pw.println("You entered the binary number " + binary);

    long decimal = 0;
    int power = 0;

    while (true) {
        if(binary == 0) {
            break;
        } else {
            long tmp = binary % 10;
            //System.out.print("tmp: " + tmp + "\n");

            decimal += tmp * Math.pow(2, power);

            //System.out.println("decimal1: " + decimal + "\n");
            //System.out.println("power: " + power + "\n");

            binary = binary / 10;

            //System.out.println("binary: " + binary + "\n");
            power++;
        }

    }
    System.out.println("The decimal conversion is " + decimal + "\n\n");
    pw.println("The decimal conversion is " + decimal + "\n\n");
}
```

How do I fix this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the overloaded version of [`nextLong`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLong%28int%29) to read binary input

```
binary = num.nextLong(2);
```

Comment: I need to print out the binary input and decimal conversion.  This is doing the conversion for me.

Comment: Then you'll have to re-think your approach, e.g. read the input as a `String` instead since Java `longs` as simple 64bit types - displaying as binary/decimal, etc. is a function of `String` formatting

Comment: That is what I thought I needed to do.  How do you use math operations on a string?  Sorry, for the basic question.

Comment: That's a whole different question. Attempt this yourself and post a new question if you get stuck :)

Answer (score 0):

It is very obvious that the value you are entering is typically going out of the range of a Long variable.

So Please try and use something like a `double` in your case which has far bigger range than long.

You will need to change your code a bit in order to work with double.

Hope this helps!
Good Luck!